# bash difference between variable assignment directly and read by while loop from a file

Tags: bash, shell

There is a difference between variable assignment directly and read by while loop from a file in bash. See the example below. `url1` and `url2` are different. how to make `url1` as `url2` represents in the `while` loop in bash? Thank you.
It does not work in `zsh 5.3.1 (x86_64-debian-linux-gnu)` or `GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` in Debian.

cat 1.csv (Note: there is a new null line in the last line of 1.csv.)

```
mgm4447943.3
mgm4447944.3
```

code:

```
#! /bin/bash

while read -r MGRAST_ID; do

echo $MGRAST_ID
url1=http://api.metagenomics.anl.gov/1/download/${MGRAST_ID}?file=050.1
echo $url1

MGRAST_ID1="mgm4447943.3"
url2=http://api.metagenomics.anl.gov/1/download/${MGRAST_ID1}?file=050.1
echo $url2

done < 1.csv
```

The output will be

```
mgm4447943.3
?file=050.1metagenomics.anl.gov/1/download/mgm4447943.3
http://api.metagenomics.anl.gov/1/download/mgm4447943.3?file=050.1
mgm4447944.3
?file=050.1metagenomics.anl.gov/1/download/mgm44GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)47944.3
http://api.metagenomics.anl.gov/1/download/mgm4447943.3?file=050.1
```

Comment: I've executed your code with bash v4.4.23 and url1 is printed correctly. What shell are you using?

Comment: @hnicke GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) in Debian stretch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have a problem with line endings. Your output implies the script uses Windows line endings, with `$MGRAST_ID` picking up a stray carriage return.

If you run the script through `dos2unix` it should run as expected. You'll also want to set your text editor to use Unix line endings.

Comment: In debian, with `GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`